# How many case fans does a Thermaltake Versa H22 have?

Tags: fan

I know this may not be the right place to post this but I couldn't find anywhere else. I also couldn't find the answer to this so I was wondering if anyone who bought one knew. If there is a correct place for this question I will be happy to move it.

Comment: Stick your finger through various holes and count how many times it hurts.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer cases and NOT electronic design.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronics design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://www.thermaltake.com.au/products-model.aspx?id=C_00002244) says that thermaltake versa H22 have preinstalled one 120mm rear exhaust fan, optional 2 x 120mm intake fans to optimize system ventilation with dust filter.

Comment: Thanks man, I think I missed that. :D I'll mark as correct in a few mins.

Comment: @Pyroglyph this question is actually off-topic.

Comment: Yes I realise that now. I just didn't know where to post it.

Answer (score 0):

Online information (not too hard to find) states it has room for 2 x 120 mm fans. Though most sources say the front is optional, so whether it actually comes with a front depends where you buy it.
And yes, this is not the proper area, I will flag it.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount 2 120mm fans in the front but the front panel is not easy to get off for cleaning and the airflow from front to back is not the best. You can also mount 2 120mm fans on the top of the case.

Comment: This question was already answered, 6 years ago, with the sake information, and your answer doesn't add anything new. Please only add answers to old questions if you have new and important information to add.